# Randomize UIView's on the same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to apply UIDynamic Kit to a project on iOS.
I have one object (A view only) and a barrier (another view).
What i am doing here is that my object bounces on the barrier.
The barrier gets placed at the defined location, now how can i randomize the location of the barrier and have multiple barriers without writing the code for each of them!?
This is the code for my barrier.

```
 UIView *myBarrier = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(5, 400, 300, 30))];
myBarrier.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:myBarrier];
```

Answer (score -1):

create a function random and use this random function to get the x & y of the view to move. Set the frame the uiview everytime you want to change the position.

int rand_lim(int limit) {
/* return a random number between 1 and limit inclusive.
 */

```
NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(N) + 1;
return r;
```

}

```
CGRect f=CGRectMake(rand_lim(self.view.frame.size.width),rand_lim(self.view.frame.size.height), myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height-self.emergencyContactView.frame.origin.y-50);
[myView setFrame:f];
```